# Backup, Version Control, or Something Else?

Tags: server, backup, git, svn

So currently I have a number of files including video, images, audio and source code on a local machine. My current procedure is to zip up the folders I know have been altered and copy the resulting file onto a removable drive as my backup and historical reference. Now as you can gather the size of these backups is growing rapidly and much of that space is wasted as 90% of the content hasn't changed.

I don't think I need full blown version control as im not to interested in tracking single changes the the folders as a hole, but I would like to be able to make a couple clicks on my windows desktop and then any updated files go off to the server, and then if needed I can grab a copy of the files from a previous date.

tldr - Backup files from windows machine to headless Ubuntu server for historical reference/snapshot.

Comment: Normally I'd say use rsync, but there are not a lot of good rsync versions in windows.

Comment: This seems like a question asking for recommendations of a Windows backup application. Since Ubuntu speaks Windows Networking (we call it *samba*), the Ubuntu part should be fairly easy (though the configuration file can be a bit of a weedpatch) and most Windows backup or sync applications should work well.